# Can't load library: /Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna10957970510011304471.tmp , spring-boot:building-image

Tags: java, spring-boot, apple-m1, jna

I have problem with building image in Intellij, I think it occurs because of my M1 macbook.

Can't load library: /Users/.../Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna10957970510011304471.tmp

I tried use JNA maven dependenecny but it give nothing and changing JDK/Spring versions. I also put jar with jna to temp folder. Any ideas ? ;/

My dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.in28minutes.microservices</groupId>
<artifactId>currency-exchange-service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>currency-exchange-service-docker</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>16</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
    </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka- 
client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <image>
                    <name>ingllot/mmv2-${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
                </image>
                <pullPolicy>IF_NOT_PRESENT</pullPolicy>
            </configuration>                
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to provide a lot more detail about what you've tried for us to help you. Please edit your question to include which versions you've tried, how you have included them in Maven. Are you using the latest version of all dependencies?

Comment: I've started to get this error as well. There must be some recent update that caused it.

Comment: I updated the info about dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed pom.xml like this and it works fine. It was version problem. I changed java, spring boot and spring cloud versions. Note that if u change spring version so spring cloud and spring boot need to contain version compatibility.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.5</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.in28minutes.microservices</groupId>
 <artifactId>currency-exchange-service</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>currency-exchange-service-docker</name>
 <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

 <properties>
  <java.version>17</java.version>
  <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
 </properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
     <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
  </dependency>

<!--      <dependency>-->
<!--         <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>-->
<!--         <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>-->
<!--      </dependency>-->

  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
     <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
     <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>

 <build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
           <image>
              
<name>ingllot/mmv2-${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
           </image>
           <pullPolicy>IF_NOT_PRESENT</pullPolicy>
        </configuration>            
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

 <repositories>
  <repository>
     <id>spring-milestones</id>
     <name>Spring Milestones</name>
     <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>

</project>
```